# Rails - find or create by - for and array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do a `XXX.find_or_create_by(title: "test")`
but with an array of titles.

Now, if I do

```
XXX.where(title: ["title1", "title2"]).first_or_create
```

it will only check for the first title

logic with a `first_or_create`

But I want to do it for ANY titles ..
any idea?

Thanks !

Comment: `XXX.create([{ title: 'title1' }, { title: 'title2' }])` this way you can create by sending array of any titles

Comment: I want to keep the logic to return the object if it already exist (that's why I put the `first_or_create`, and not just the `create`)

Comment: do you have validation on model uniqueness ? it is good to add a validation on model for uniqueness

Comment: another bad way you can do `["title1", "title2"].map{|t| XXX.where(title: t).first_or_create}`

Comment: the purpose is to keep it with minimum sql request (there will be 10 000 titles sometimes)

Comment: create the record batches see the link https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/ and use some background jobs like `sidekiq` `resque` adapter of Activejob for doing this

Comment: hmm...sounds like a bug

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work

```
XXX.where("title IN ('title1','title2',''title3)").first_or_create
```

Comment: same, return only the first

Answer (score 0):

I think you will you want to do something like:

```
found_titles = XXX.where(title: [array_of_titles]).pluck(:title)

to_be_created = [array_of_titles] - found_titles

XXX.create(
  to_be_created.map{ |title| {title: title} }
)

return XXX.where(title: [array_of_titles])
```